# Hazelcast client subscriber not receiving message

Tags: java, docker, publish-subscribe, hazelcast

We are running Hazelcast Java client app in one docker container & hazelcast server with single member in other container on same machine.

Our client app is able to connect to hz server container & play around with data but pub/sub is not working.

Both pub/sub threads are running in client app itself. Data is getting published as it can be seen in Hazelcast management center but it's not getting received.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

PS: We are using hazelcast v5.1.3 with default server & client config.

Comment: Can you share a simple reproducer? I am able to publish and receive the topic messages (both reliable and normal) in the same client application.

Comment: @mdumandag Thanks for your response but this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue by replacing hazelcast-5.3.1 jar with hazelcast-client-4.x jar in our client app docker image.

Posting an answer here just in case if someone faces similar issue.

Comment: Downgrading isn't a good solution. If you can share a reproducer the problem can be fixed so you can upgrade.

Comment: @NeilStevenson yes, i agree..downgrading isn't a good soln. will share a reproducer asap

Comment: If you can, try removing Docker and running on localhost. That'll help confirm if Docker is irrelevant or the reason.

Comment: Is there any update on this ? If the problem can recreate it can be fixed.